# Compose functions with template in C++ got segmentation fault

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a demo to chain various functions into one, just like `chain(f, g)(x) = g(f(x))`, it is OK when I chain lambdas, but with named functions, I got a segmentation fault, I'm now struggling with it.

My code:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename G>
constexpr auto chain(F&& f, G&& g) {
  return [&](auto x) {
    return g(f(x));
  };
}

template <typename F, typename... Fs>
constexpr auto chain(F&& f, Fs&&... fs) {
  return chain(f, chain(fs...));
}

int add1(int x) {
  return x + 1;
}

int times2(int x) {
  return x * 2;
}

int add10(int x) {
  return x + 10;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto f = chain(
      [](int x) { return x + 1; },
      [](int x) { return x * 2; },
      [](int x) { return x + 10; });
  printf("result: %d\n", f(2)); // Here is OK
  auto g = chain(add1, times2, add10);
  printf("result: %d\n", g(2)); // Here I got a segmentation fault and I don't know why
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your non-variadic `chain` function template returns a lambda that captures the arguments `f` and `g` by reference. These references are dangling when you return from `chain`, and invoking the returned lambda invokes undefined behavior.

As is the case with undefined behavior, it can appear to work sometimes, and can cause a segmentation fault at other times. There is of course no guarantee of this behavior.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your answer.
p.s. I'm new to C++, does capture by values is inefficient? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: @Artiano  If you're new to C++ don't focus on the efficiency aspect at first, focus on the correctness instead. This is true of any language of course, but is particularly relevant to C++ which gives you reasonable efficiency by default. In this case, capturing by value should be fine.

Comment: `can cause a segmentation fault at other times` I know you already know this, but just for other people reading in the future who may not know, it doesn't even have to cause a segmentation fault. There's really no telling what Undefined Behavior will do.